# "Enchantment Creatures" and "Enchanted Creatures"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is a enchantment creature card considered to be a creature that is enchanted? I need to know for [Winds of Rath](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Winds%20of%20Rath), which destroys all creatures that aren't enchanted.

Comment: This Q&A is more far more referenceable than the one Jefromi mentioned. I'd rather close the other one if either is going to get closed.

Answer (score 1):

No. An enchanted creature is one that has an aura enchantment enchanting it.

> 303.4b The object or player an Aura is attached to is called "enchanted."